# Codeigniter validation issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Messaging system uses same function to send and reply to messages. One user sends a message to another with subject: "just testing £69 $100 @ ha". And message contains text, php, and html. PHP gets stripped out by CI xss_clean and html is blocked/replaced by the system. It gets sent with no errors. Other user receives it, opens it and tries to reply with a plain text of 47 chars. CI form validation class blocks it and displays error: Subject must be under 1000 characters. The first and most important issue is that it shouldn't trigger a validation error. Secondly CI form val. has subject set to max. 30 chars, and the message set to max 1000 chars - so the error message is also incorrect. My hunch is that one of the characters in the subject is upsetting CI form val. but it didn't upset it when the original message was sent! Any idea what's going on here?

Here's the relevant code from the form;

```
<form name="sendmessage" method="POST" action="<? echo base_url(); ?>user/messaging/sendmessage/">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="recipiant" value="<? echo $message['mem_msg_from_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="thread" value="<? echo $message['mem_msg_thread_id']; ?>" />
        <? if(substr($message['mem_msg_subject'],3) == 'Re:'){$subject = $message['mem_msg_subject'];}else{$subject = 'Re: ' . $message['mem_msg_subject'];} ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<? echo ucfirst($subject); ?>">
```

And here's the controller code;

```
 public function sendmessage(){
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){ // ajax request only
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject',TRUE);
        $message = $this->input->post('message',TRUE);
        $recipiant = $this->input->post('recipiant',TRUE);
        $thread_id = $this->input->post('thread',TRUE);

        $subject_val = $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $subject_req_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'A %s is required!');
        $subject_min_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s must be at least 3 characters!');
        $subject_max_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', '%s must be under 30 characters!');

        $message_val = $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[1000]');
        $message_req_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'A %s is required!');
        $message_min_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s must be at least 5 characters!');
        $message_max_error = $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', '%s must be under 1000 characters!');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="pull-left">','&nbsp;</div><br>');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){ // FAILED TRY AGAIN
            echo '<div style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">' . form_error('subject') . form_error('message') . '</div>';
        }else{ // ALL SEEMS TO BE IN ORDER HERE

            // clean it up a bit
            $subject = str_replace('<', '', $subject);
            $subject = str_replace('>', '' , $subject);
            $subject = auto_link($subject, 'both', TRUE);

            $message = str_replace('<', '', $message);
            $message = str_replace('>', '' , $message);
            $message = auto_link($message, 'both', TRUE);

            // stick it in the database
            $db = $this->user_messaging_model->sendMessage($this->userinfo['user_id'], $recipiant, $subject, $message, $thread_id);

            echo 'sent';
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: have you loaded form helper?

Comment: @sandip Yep it would throw an error if I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-writing the messages assigned for the rules.

Please note that `$this->form_validation->set_message` works per rule. Not, per field per rule. So, when you set `$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length'...` for the second time, it over-writes the initial message assigned to the 'max_length' requirement.

In general you do not need to set messages for these, codeigniter itself will generate a decent error message based on your requirement.

In my workflow, I generally use `set_message` function to generate messages to custom callback validations we do on form fields.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I haven't quite got my head around CI's validation class yet. However, that isn't causing the problem. To get around the problem for now I have bypassed validation of the subject for replies as the subject is uneditable for replies and has already passed validation when the original message was sent. This doesn't remove the fact that there is a problem though, possibly with CI's validation class and possibly the UK pound character "£".

Comment: You should not bypass validation because a field is not editable - anyone who knows how to use Firebug will change the form to whatever they want. The validation class will validate whatever you tell it to validate the special characters are not really an issue based on the rules you have posted.